# How to write a word to beginning of each line in a notepad txt file? C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I want to write a string to the beginning of each line in a text file DATA.txt.

Input:

```
Hello 
my 
name 
is 
steven
```

Output:

```
1.hello
1.my
1.name
1.is
1.steven
```

I want to find the string on each line then put the certain text `1.` before it.

Comment: Post some code that you have written to try to solve this, together with a specific question regarding the code.

Comment: I havent got any code ive tried to make it but failed so dleted all my projects related to this so I was hoping a reference would be in tact

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what this has to do with notepad. If you want to prepend each line in a text file with a string, simply

1. read the file line-wise
2. output the prefix to a new file
3. output the line contents to the new file
4. read next line and go to 2 until you reached the end of the file.

If this is not what you want you should ask more specifically.

Comment: I guess the notepad reference comes from the ".txt is the native application file format of the mighty notepad" idea. Many people see it this way.

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following code will be of help to you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line, new_content;
    string prefix   = "1.";
    char filename[] = "DATA.txt";

    // Read lines and prepare contents by prefixing lines with a prefix
    ifstream infile(filename);
    while ( infile >> line ) {
        new_content += prefix + line + "\n";
    }
    infile.close();

    // Write contents
    ofstream outfile(filename);
    outfile << new_content;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark, but do you mean that it should read an existing text file to get the lines of text?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("c:\\input.txt");
    std::ofstream outputFile("c:\\output.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
        outputFile << "1." << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which means, open the input file and the output file, and then for each line read from the input file, write it to the output file with `1.` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of something that C++ should not be used for. If you were on Unix, you'd do

```
cat myFile.txt | sed 's/^/1./
```

On Windows, I am sure you can do something with bat files or the new shell (PowerSomething?). Please don't use C++ for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question.

However, you should choose which tool to use with care. Neither notepad nor C++ look like the right tool for the job you want. You should use sed, perl, or a good text editor (vim).

Answer (score 0):

I think a brief refresher on standard I/O through cout statements is in order.  You can print to the console via the "cout" function which is invoked in the following example:

```
cout << "I used a cout statement, lolz";
```

Similarly you can print a newline to the console via the newline character "\n" or using "<< endl" at the end of a "cout" statement

```
cout << "This is the newline character \n";
cout << "This is endl" << endl;
```

I hope this helps.  Remember that in order to use cout you need to include the iostream library.

Answer (score 0):

One posssible way to do it.

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //use for a series of numbers
    int i=0;
    // or use if you want 1 number
    int j=1;

    ofstream out ("yourfile.txt", ios::app);

    //use j if you want to display 1 with dot (.)
    out << i++ << "." << "Hello" << endl;
    out << i++ << "." << "my" << endl;
    out << i++ << "." << "name" << endl;
    out << i++ << "." << "is" << endl;
    out << i++ << "." << "Steven" << endl;
}
```

EDIT: Same code with string!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string strText[] = {
            "Hello",
            "my",
            "name",
            "is",
            "steven"
            };

        //use for a series of numbers
        int i=0;
        // or use if you want 1 number
        int j=1;

        ofstream out ("yourfile.txt", ios::app);

        //use j if you want to display 1 with dot (.)
        out << i++ << "." << strText[0] << endl;
        out << i++ << "." << strText[1] << endl;
        out << i++ << "." << strText[2] << endl;
        out << i++ << "." << strText[3] << endl;
        out << i++ << "." << strText[4] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I want it to find the string and place it before the text 
on each line

Answer (score 0):

Just use a prefix variable:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream file;
string prefix = "1. ";

out_file.open("test.txt");

out_file << prefix << "some text" << endl;
out_file << prefix << "some other text" << endl;

out_file.close();
```

Or you could write a little convenience function to do this:

```
void writeLine(ofstream file, string text)
{
    file << "1. " << text << endl;
}
```

Certainly, there are more possibilites.